# Issues with dynamically setting style.overflow in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, html

I am working on a website for a client, and we have the following requirements:

1. When the browser width is greater than 960px don't show a scroll bar.
2. When the content is wider than the browser but the browser width is greater than 960 don't show the scroll bar
3. If the browser is 960px don't show the scroll bar when it is needed.

I have the following javascript that works perfectly under ie, chrome, safari and opera, but dies in FF by forcing the page to "reload" client side (it redraws all elements).

```
function sizeHandler(myWidth) {
    if (myWidth > 960)
        document.documentElement.style.overflowX = 'hidden';
    else
        document.documentElement.style.overflowX = 'auto';
}
```

Because everyone seems to question the content, here is the HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="flashContent">
        <object...>
        </object>
    </div>
</body>
<script...>$(document).ready(sizeHandler(getWidth()));</script>
```

Ignore getWidth(), it works, but I don't feel like adding another 15 lines to this ;).  The object tag is a flash object.

Comment: How is the sizeHandler() linked to events?

Comment: The function being called isn't the problem, we use jQuery to call it when the DOM is ready.  The problem is FF redraws all child elements when the overflow is set dynamically.

Comment: Your code works for me on FF 3.05 (using firebug to run the code). No redraw whatsoever.

Comment: Place a flash animation, allow the flash to load some part of the way, then resize.

Comment: Could you extract the core parts of the page to reproduce the issue and post a link? There might be something we're all missing.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with document.body instead of document.documentElement. Setting CSS properties on the HTML element can give unexpected quirks.

Comment: It still redraws the inner elements.